# Flutter App Crashing after adding firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, dart

Hi my app is crashing and i can't seem to find the problem.I looked at the logcat but did not seem to find anything there as well.
Here is the logcat:

```html
2021-01-27 10:07:31.021 22855-22855/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2021-01-27 10:07:31.024 22855-22855/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G935T_8.0.0_0017, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
2021-01-27 10:07:31.024 9516-9526/? I/zygote64: Background concurrent copying GC freed 92780(5MB) AllocSpace objects, 10(200KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 8MB/17MB, paused 700us total 256.685ms
2021-01-27 10:07:31.025 22855-22855/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=platform, pkgname=com.samsung.android.app.assistantmenu 
2021-01-27 10:07:31.076 1461-4979/? I/ActivityManager: DSS on for com.samsung.android.app.assistantmenu and scale is 1.0
2021-01-27 10:07:31.103 1461-1903/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:956 com.android.server.execute.SemExecuteManagerService.sendCompleteBroadcast:138 com.android.server.execute.SemExecuteManagerService.updateSemExecutableInfo:131 com.android.server.execute.SemExecuteManagerService.-wrap2:0 com.android.server.execute.SemExecuteManagerService$MyPackageMonitor.onSomePackagesChanged:173 
2021-01-27 10:07:31.128 22855-22855/? I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
2021-01-27 10:07:31.140 3936-4055/? W/Launcher.Model: checkFinderState return, operation is not matched
2021-01-27 10:07:31.173 22855-22855/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1483 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:663 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:663 com.samsung.android.app.assistantmenu.AssistantMenuReceiver.onReceive:473 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3392 
2021-01-27 10:07:31.186 3936-4055/? I/ApplicationPackageManager: load=NULL, bg=144-144, dr=192-192, forDefault=true, density=640
2021-01-27 10:07:31.187 3936-4055/? I/ApplicationPackageManager: scaled rate=0.72, size=192, alpha=4, hold=102
2021-01-27 10:07:31.190 3936-4055/? I/ApplicationPackageManager: load=NULL-contain, bg=256-256, dr=192-192
2021-01-27 10:07:31.195 1461-9802/? I/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice user:0
2021-01-27 10:07:31.195 1461-9802/? I/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice user:0
2021-01-27 10:07:31.243 22878-22878/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-01-27 10:07:31.245 22878-22878/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2021-01-27 10:07:31.245 22878-22878/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2021-01-27 10:07:31.259 22878-22878/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G935T_8.0.0_0017, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
2021-01-27 10:07:31.260 22878-22878/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=platform, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice:edgelighting 
2021-01-27 10:07:31.302 1461-9802/? W/ActivityManager: Slow operation: 107ms so far, now at startProcess: building log message
2021-01-27 10:07:31.302 1461-9802/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 22878:com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice:edgelighting/u0a11 for broadcast com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice/com.samsung.android.app.edgelighting.EdgeLightingReceiver
2021-01-27 10:07:31.304 1461-9802/? W/ActivityManager: Slow operation: 108ms so far, now at startProcess: starting to update pids map
2021-01-27 10:07:31.304 1461-9802/? W/ActivityManager: Slow operation: 109ms so far, now at startProcess: done updating pids map
2021-01-27 10:07:31.304 1461-9802/? W/ActivityManager: Slow operation: 109ms so far, now at startProcess: done starting proc!
2021-01-27 10:07:31.309 3936-4055/? I/AppsModel: addOrUpdater
2021-01-27 10:07:31.309 3936-4055/? I/AppsModel: addOrUpdater cn = ComponentInfo{com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope/com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope.MainActivity} , UserHandle{0}
2021-01-27 10:07:31.311 1461-4979/? I/ActivityManager: DSS on for com.samsung.android.app.cocktailbarservice and scale is 1.0
2021-01-27 10:07:31.315 3936-4055/? I/AppsModel: addOrUpdater update item = IconInfo(title=multiPurposeScope intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope/.MainActivity (has extras) } id=95 type=0 container=-102 screen=1 cellX=1 cellY=0 spanX=1 spanY=1 rank=1 hidden=0 dropPos=null user=UserHandle{0})
2021-01-27 10:07:31.319 3936-4055/? I/PostPositionController: addItem() - com.akdndhrc.multipurposescope, isWidgetOnly : true
2021-01-27 10:07:31.331 1461-9802/? I/ActivityManager: KPU : put [com.sec.android.app.shealth:remote] : 35434 K
2021-01-27 10:07:31.332 1461-9802/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 22203:com.sec.android.app.shealth:remote/u0a52 (adj 906): DHA:empty #25
2021-01-27 10:07:31.356 22878-22878/? I/zygote64: no shared libraies, dex_files: 1
2021-01-27 10:07:31.403 1461-3920/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.android.app.shealth/com.samsung.android.service.health.HealthService in 1000ms
2021-01-27 10:07:31.432 1461-3898/? W/StorageManager: getStorageLowBytes lowPercent : 5, lowBytes : 1284408729, maxLowBytes : 524288000
2021-01-27 10:07:31.438 1461-2790/? I/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:com.sec.android.app.shealth user:0
2021-01-27 10:07:31.438 1461-2790/? I/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:com.sec.android.app.shealth user:0
2021-01-27 10:07:31.474 1461-2790/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 22893:com.sec.android.app.shealth:remote/u0a52 for service com.sec.android.app.shealth/com.samsung.android.service.health.HealthService
2021-01-27 10:07:31.504 22893-22893/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-01-27 10:07:31.509 22893-22893/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
2021-01-27 10:07:31.509 22893-22893/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
```

The problem started arose after i tried to implement firebase authentication in my project.

Comment: You may not have added google-services.json file and gradle plugin when setting up the project. Please refer installation guide to properly setup the project https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android

Comment: Just double checked the google-services.json file is present and the dependencies of gradle are also implemented

Comment: Did you add firebase_core to the project? Make sure you have called `await Firebase.initializeApp();`  as in the documentation. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

Comment: @Udara done this is still crashing any recommendations

Comment: Do i share my code?